# python 3.12 f-string inelegance

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

```
MY_WIDTH = 80
MY_CONSTRUCTED_HDR = f"this is a hdr of length {MY_WIDTH}"
print(MY_CONSTRUCTED_HDR)
```

this is a hdr of length 80   # YES, but NOT what I need -- see below
I want something like this --

```
                   this is a hdr of length 80
```

and I miggghht even add another variable or two into the header at some point
depending on how gabby the app is

Other constructs I tried --

```
#MY_CONSTRUCTED_HDR = f"this is a hdr of length {MY_WIDTH} : ^{MY_WIDTH}" # NO prints : ^80

#MY_CONSTRUCTED_HDR = f"{this is a hdr of length {MY_WIDTH}" : ^{MY_WIDTH}} # NO prints : ^80, lots of highlighted syntax errors

#MY_CONSTRUCTED_HDR = f"(this is a hdr of length {MY_WIDTH}" : ^{MY_WIDTH}) # NO prints : ^80, syntax errors

#MY_CONSTRUCTED_HDR = f"{'this is a hdr of length {MY_WIDTH}' : ^{MY_WIDTH}}" # this is CLOSE, prints centered BUT MY_WIDTH in header prints MY_WIDTH, not 80

#MY_CONSTRUCTED_HDR = f"{'this is a hdr of length {MY_WIDTH:2d}' : ^{MY_WIDTH}}" # NO, centers but prints MY_WIDTH:2d
```

This works but it's two steps:

```
hdr_string = f"this is a hdr of length {MY_WIDTH}"
MY_CONSTRUCTED_HDR = f"{hdr_string: ^{MY_WIDTH}}" # 
print(MY_CONSTRUCTED_HDR)
```

Really would like one line of code
any ideas? f-strings preferred bc the header text and variables
can change radically

Comment: I might recommend looking at the formatting of this question/revising it because it is not clear what you are asking about, some of which may be more clear if the formatting was fixed up.  Are you trying to right-align something?

Comment: Apparently you want the string to be padded with leading and trailing spaces. Showing it in quotation marks rather than just indented would make that clearer: `"                            this is a hdr of length 80                            "` (though the line wrapping in this comment doesn't help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested f-string, with the outer f-string formatting the inner f-string:

```
MY_WIDTH = 80
print(f"{f"this is a hdr of length {MY_WIDTH}":^{MY_WIDTH}}")
```

Note that prior to Python 3.12, you cannot use the same quotation mark for an outer f-string, so you would have to do something like:

```
print(f'{f"this is a hdr of length {MY_WIDTH}":^{MY_WIDTH}}')
```

Comment: weird, but this *is* the way. thank you blhsing